# Rewrite entire mq4 code to mq5 equivarent

Tags: mql4, mql5

I have this code. I want to rewrite it as mq5. I want to know how many mt5 buffers plots to include.
I have used converters but every time I try to compile I get compile errors. That is why I decided to rewrite the entire file.

```
#property version   "1.002"

#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers 2
#property indicator_color1 DeepSkyBlue
#property indicator_color2 Red
#property indicator_width1  2
#property indicator_width2  2
```

Comment: two buffers to plot, and two `INDICATOR_CALCULATE` buffers for the last two ones

Comment: Hello @DanielKniaz, kindly clarify a bit with example if possible.

Comment: Show the full code (or simplified, in order to let the code be MCVE) in order to receive more help